# What does being Born Again mean per Catholic teaching?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, exegesis

**What does being Born Again mean per Catholic teaching?**

> Jesus answered and said to him, “Most assuredly, I say to you, unless one is born again, he cannot see the kingdom of God.” (John 3:3 NKJV)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No 1213 [Catechism of the Catholic Church under THE SACRAMENT OF BAPTISM](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c1a1.htm) summarises what baptism is:

> 1213 Holy Baptism is the basis of the whole Christian life, the
>   gateway to life in the Spirit *(vitae spiritualis ianua)* [4 Cf.
>   Council Of Florence: DS 1314: *vitae spiritualis ianua*.], and the
>   door which gives access to the other sacraments. **Through Baptism we
>   are freed from sin and reborn as [sons of
>   God](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/what-is-unique-about-christianity/30905#30905);
>   we become members of Christ, are incorporated into the Church and made
>   sharers in her mission: "Baptism is the sacrament of regeneration
>   through water in the word."** [*Roman Catechism* II,2,5; Cf. Council
>   Of Florence: DS 1314; CIC, cann. 204 § 1; 849; CCEO, can. 675 § 1.]

The answer to the question is in bold.